# solve system of differential equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of differential equations in Matlab.

[image]

```
dn/du=(-2*u*n-K*(n*u-(1+g)))/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/n))

dxi/du=(1-u^2)/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/n))

df/du=(2*u+K*u^2*(u-(1+g)/n))/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/n))
```

K and gamma are constants. I have the initial conditions like so:

```
n(0)=1, xi(0)=0, f(0)=0
```

First i tried to use 'dsolve'.

```
g=0.1;
K=3;

syms n(u) u 
n(u)=dsolve(diff(n,u)== (-2*u*n-K*(n*u-(1+g)))/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/n)),n(0)==1)

syms x(u) u n
x(u)= dsolve(diff(x,u)== (1-u^2)/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/n)),x(0)==0)

syms f(u) u n
f(u)=dsolve(diff(f,u)== (2*u+K*u^2*(u-(1+g)/n))/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/n)),f(0)==0)
```

from this i get that there is not explicit solution for the first equation and returned an [empty sym] as shown below.

> Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.
>
> In dsolve (line 201)
>
> In Untitled (line 37)
>
> **n(u)** = 
>   [ empty sym ]
>
> **x(u)** =
>    (1089*atan(33/(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2) - (80*n*u)/(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2)))/(160*n*(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2)) - (35937*log(40*n*u^2 - 33*u + 10*n))/(2*(- 256000*n^3 + 174240*n)) - u/4 + (33*log(10*n)*(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2) - 2178*atan(33/(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2)) + 8000*n^2*atan(33/(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2)))/(320*n*(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2)) - (25*n*atan(33/(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2) - (80*n*u)/(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2)))/(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2) + (26400*n^2*log(40*n*u^2 - 33*u + 10*n))/(- 256000*n^3 + 174240*n)
>
> **f(u)** =
>    (3*u^2)/8 - (33*u)/(160*n) - (log(40*n*u^2 - 33*u + 10*n)*(3200000*n^4 - 3920400*n^2 + 1185921))/(2*(- 10240000*n^4 + 6969600*n^2)) + (log(10*n)*(3200000*n^4 - 3920400*n^2 + 1185921))/(2*(- 10240000*n^4 + 6969600*n^2)) + (33*atan((1089*(2800*n^2 - 1089))/((1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2)*(92400*n^2 - 35937)))*(2800*n^2 - 1089))/(6400*n^2*(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2)) - (33*atan((1089*(2800*n^2 - 1089))/((1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2)*(92400*n^2 - 35937)) - (2640*n*u*(2800*n^2 - 1089))/((1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2)*(92400*n^2 - 35937)))*(2800*n^2 - 1089))/(6400*n^2*(1600*n^2 - 1089)^(1/2))

Then i tried to use 'ode45'.

```
u=0:0.1:1;
K=3;
g=0.1;
dndu=@(u,n) (-2*u*n-K*(n*u-(1+g)))/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/n));
[u,n]=ode45(dndu, u, 1) % initial n=1

dxidu=@(u,xi) (1-u^2)/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/n));
[u,xi]=ode45(dxidu, u, 0); %initial xi=0

dfdu=@(u,f) (2*u+K*u^2*(u-(1+g)/n))/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/n));
[u,f]=ode45(dfdu, u, 0) %initial f=0
```

K and g are constants and u gets values for 0 to 1.
When i run this the first equation is solved and got an answer for u and n but i get an error for the second equation that matrix dimension must agree as shown below.

> u =
>            0
>       0.1000
>       0.2000
>       0.3000
>       0.4000
>       0.5000
>       0.6000
>       0.7000
>       0.8000
>       0.9000
>       1.0000
>
> n =
>       1.0000
>       1.3409
>       1.6243
>       1.7746
>       1.7945
>       1.7263
>       1.6119
>       1.4800
>       1.3470
>       1.2208
>       1.1048
>
> Error using  /
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in @(u,xi)(1-u^2)/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/n))
>
> Error in odearguments (line 87)
>   f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.
>
> Error in ode45 (line 113)
>   [neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...
>
> Error in ode45method (line 24)
>   [u,xi]=ode45(dxidu, u, 0); %initial xi=0

Can anyone help me how to approach this type of problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the editing Deena and m.s

Answer (score 2):

You have a system of **coupled** differential equations, you need to solve it as a coupled system. One ODE function for a vector valued function with 3 components.

Comment: Thanks LutzL, i did put all three equations in one ode function and it's working!

Answer (score 2):

```
u1=0:0.01:1;
K=3;
g=0.1;
dydu=@(u,y)[(-2*u*y(1)-K*(y(1)*u-(1+g)))/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/y(1)))
        (1-u^2)/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/y(1)))
        (2*u+K*u^2*(u-(1+g)/y(1)))/(1+u^2+K*u*(u-(1+g)/y(1)))];
[U,Y]=ode45(dydu,u1,[1 0 0]);
n=Y(:,1);
xi=Y(:,2);
f=Y(:,3);
```